# How does "favorites" activity notification work?

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks

I don't get how notifications work for the "favorites" tab on my personal page. Others seem to appear only when there has been new activity, but "favorites" just fires up without obvious reasons. I mean there is specifically a part that tells me when the last activity was, and it says it was like a month ago, and yesterday there was no notification about any activity, so I wonder if it was stuck for a month, or there is some hidden activity that doesn't show in the tab.